# create select JPQL Query throw exception

Tags: java, jquery, hibernate, jpa

I have two objects

```
Person(long id, String name, PersonInfo info)
```

and

```
PersonInfo(long id, String email, String lastname, in age)
```

now I try to create a `javax.persistence.Query`

i try to create `select to person where personinfo.email="somemail"`

i try

```
String queryString="select Person from Person p where p.PersonInfo._email='somemail'";
Query query=emf.createQuery(queryString);
List resultList = query.getResultList();
```

but i get this exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: PersonInfo of: Entities.Person [select Person from Entities.Person p where p.PersonInfo._email='somemail'] [Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@748e6591
```

what i'm dong wrong?

Comment: Not sure, but isn't it rather `SELECT p from Person p`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about the following query string:

```
String queryString="select p from Person p where p.personInfo.email='somemail'";
```

Comment: now i get it for me -->  String queryString="select p from Person p where p.personInfo._email='somemail'";  grrr damn upper/lower case thanks

Comment: Is there no issue with '_email'?